# Why use Tomcat instead of regular Apache Web Server

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, rest, soap

I'm building an iphone application that will need to communicate and exchange data with a server.

My plan is to exchange messages in SOAP format and have PHP/Apache handle the processing/response. My question is, what could Tomcat/JSP/Servlets do that Apache/PHP can't?

Comment: if I dared answer, it would be something like: "it would cause you to lose even more hair"... seriously, I don't think Tomcat can do any more than Apache with PHP, it's just a different approach, with a lot more complexity

Comment: @ceejayoz, how about a useful comment?

Comment: "WTF, why?" is a useful comment when you're considering SOAP when JSON and XML transports are commonly used and far easier to work with - especially when both endpoints are yours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With out any more information than "exchange SOAP messages", the answer would be "nothing".

Fundamentally, you'll likely be able to do whatever you want in some way with either, so pick the one you're most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between LAMP and "The Java approach" is
the added step of compilation. All of the languages I've heard
attached to LAMP (Perl, Python, and PHP) are languages where source
code is interpretted, whereas Java interprets bytecode. It sounds
like a small difference, but in practice, compilation adds on a
non-trivial amount of effort.

I just hope
that the Java folks look at LAMP with an open mind , and
likewise I hope that the LAMP folks look at Java with an open mind.
Java does some things well, and does other things not so well.
Likewise, LAMP does some things well, and other things not so well.
Maybe we can learn from both.

Comment: Does it provide a significant performance advantage in certain usage scenarios?

Comment: Yes, but that can be ameliorated by an opcode cache and things like Facebook's HipHop compiler for PHP.